# Can lua 5.3 do websockets?

Tags: websocket, lua

I'm trying to build a very simple websocket client in lua, and I have found a number of libraries, but I have also found a lot of problems with each library.

The biggest problem is that lua 5.3 is the current version, but no libraries seem to work with it.

- **lua-websockets** : will not work on lua 5.3 because of the luabitop dependency
- **http.websocket** : gives me connection resets whenever I try to receive messages, and the documentation is sparse when it comes to building an asynchronous websocket client.
- **turbolua** : looks great but the last update was almost a year ago, it will not build on my Mac and the website (www.turbolua.org) appears to have been hacked.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Yes, you're missing that this is Stack Overflow and not https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks... I don't think that's the right forum for this question, but I'll post over there too. In the meantime, I'm still hoping for a good answer wherever and however it comes.

Answer (score 0):

The library found on github.com/arcapos/luawebsocket works with Lua 5.3.

Comment: Isn't that a JSON library? I'm looking for a websockets library.

Comment: Although, having JSON in Lua comes in handy when using websockets to talk to JavaScript running in the browser...

Comment: That's for the suggestion, but that appears to be a server library. I'm trying to set up a client.

Comment: Be aware that the library is without an open source licence and is copyrighted.

Comment: That is not true.  It is licensed under the three-clause BSD license.  See the source code files, every file contains the license.

Comment: Yes I just noticed, my bad. But the Copyright notice and the lack of a license file is misleading imho.